# How do I make visual studio show exceptions that any method may throw?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was wondering about how I can make visual studio show the exceptions that ***any*** method may throw, not just the .NET Framework methods (I am using C#).

For example, here's a picture showing that when I hover over Console.WriteLine it says "Exceptions: System.IO.IOException".

[image]

However when I do that for any method I wrote it doesn't say what exception it throws, as shown in the following picture.

[image]

So how do I make visual studio show those exceptions? Do I need to add a specific attribute to the method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by adding an `<exception>` tag to the methods comment:

```
/// <summary>
/// Fooes this instance.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Yay for exception</exception>
public void Foo()
{ }
```

Comment: This is one feature of Java that I think would have been a good addition to C# - having to explicitly handle or redeclare exceptions that can be thrown by the code you're calling, rather than relying on xml documentation to convey it

Comment: Thanks, but how come I can't see those comments in the implementation file of Console.WriteLine() on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/? Or does microsoft delete them from there?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Andres Heljsberg [thinks differently](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Dear god no. There's a reason Java is practically the only language to use them (and that fault lies in Java's standard library horrible use of the mechanism). It's nice in theory but quickly gets out of hand.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, you are wrong http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/why-doesn-t-c-have-checked-exceptions.aspx

Comment: @Yuval Thanks for the link - interesting read. I can certainly see the arguments against them now.

Comment: @Gal Guess I should be glad I've never had to work with Java in anything too large - if I had done so, would probably have seen the other side of the argument sooner!

Comment: The answer shows how to annotate source code. A library without source code can have the built out documentation file. If you don't have it, you _could_ make one yourself.